# JPA: bidirectional relationships based on Entity map keys

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

Is it possible to specify two bidirectional relationships via a single JPA 2.x 'Map' property? Relationship associated with map key should be "many to many" while the map value is "many to one". Ideally, class with Map member variable should own both relationships. Database is being auto-generated from code so I can accept default column names assigned by persistence provider (EclipseLink). Code below illustrates how I'd expect Java entities to look. I'm just confused about which annotations to insert.

```
@Entity public class A {
    private Long mId;
    @Id @GeneratedValue public Long getId() {return mId;}
    protected void setId(Long pId) {mId = pId;}

    private Set<B> mBs;
    public Set<B> getBs() {return mBs;}
    protected void setBs(Set<B> pBs) {mBs = pBs;}
}

@Entity public class B {
    private Long mId;
    @Id @GeneratedValue public Long getId() {return mId;}
    protected void setId(Long pId) {mId = pId;}

    private Map<A,C> mAToC;
    public Map<A,C> getAToC() {return mAToC;}
    protected void setAToC(Map<A,C> pAToC) {mAToC = pAToC;}
}

@Entity public class C {
    private Long mId;
    @Id @GeneratedValue public Long getId() {return mId;}
    protected void setId(Long pId) {mId = pId;}

    private B mB;
    public B getB() {return mB;}
    protected void setB(B pB) {mB = pB;}
}
```

[JEE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#giqvn) suggests that `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` annotations can be used to declare Map **value** relationships. However, I don't see much information on Map **key** relationship specification. `@MapKeyJoinColumn` looked promising but provides no obvious way to define bidirectionality.

Comment: Just define the inverse relationship with the tags insertable=false, updatable=false to achieve the same effect.  JPA's mappedby tag is just a convenience method to mark one side essentially read-only and not have to redefine the columns.

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting nor do I see how 'mappedBy' can be "just a convenience." Without 'mappedBy' attribute, how can persistence manager derive bidirectional link between properties? I presumed that 'mappedBy' disambiguates between candidate properties of non-owning entity.

A `Map<Entity,Entity>` property captures two relationships. Both key and value reference other entities. What I need is a way to declare exactly which properties are on the other side of both bidirectional relationships. Ideal answer would insert proper annotations to code included in original question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think a bidirectional relation is, but it is just two relationships using the same foreign key information in the database - one side owns it and can write to it, the other doesn't and is read only.  JPA does not perform relationship maintenance, so it is nothing more than a read-only relationship.  So, to get this to work you will need to understand what the relation table looks like and use it on the reverse side, but mark it as insertable=false , updatable=false.  It only needs to map the fields the other side needs to know about - the foreign key column.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I am not explicitly defining database schema; it is derived from Entity class definitions. I don't understand how to write Java code that unambiguously maps to a specific schema. Consider following code:

`@Entity class A {Map<A,A> map; Set<A> set1; Set<A> set2; Set<A> set3;}`.

Annotations are necessary to link key/val of map with **specific** properties, right? I don't see how DB initialization or queries could function without persistence provider knowing how properties relate to one another. Without 'mappedBy' (or something like that), there's no way to tell.

Comment: Maybe someone can give you a working example as an answer- I was just trying to point you in the direction.  Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html for how a ManyToMany is defined.  You are using the defaults, while the otherside will need to specify the JoinTable since you cannot use mappedby to pull the relationship info from the mapping that owns the relationship.  It needs to be explicitly defined and the non-owning side marked insertable=false, updatable=false

Comment: Oh, I guess you're saying that, in this case, 'JoinTable' and 'JoinColumn' annotations are required in order to link properties between entities. Strange that this is necessary for Maps but not Sets or Lists. With the exception of this one particular `Map<Entity,Entity>` property, I'd been able to avoid explicit references to DB namespace. Rather than pollute application design, I've opted to refactor away my "entity to entity" maps. Thanks for your assistance.